# OpenCV C# Frame Differencing

Tags: c#, opencv, computer-vision

I'm new to computer vision and currently playing around with static frame differencing to try and determine whether there is motion in video.

My variables:

```
public Mat currentFrame = new Mat();
public Mat prevFrame = new Mat();
public Mat result = new Mat();
bool motion = false;
```

Simple differencing function (being called every frame):

```
public Mat getDifference(Mat videoFrame)
{
    currentFrame = videoFrame.Clone();
    Cv2.Absdiff(currentFrame, prevFrame, result);
    prevFrame = currentFrame.Clone();
    return result;
}
```

When motion exists the result matrix looks like this:
[image]

When motion doesn't exist the result matrix looks like this (empty):
[image]

My original idea was that if the result matrix is effectively empty (all black), then I could say motion = false. However, this is proving to be more difficult that anticipated since it is technically never empty, so I can't say:

```
if(!result.Empty())
{
    motion = true;
}
```

Without the need of for loops and pixel by pixel analysis, is there a simple/clean 'if' statement I can use that simply says (if the matrix contains anything that isn't black pixels, motion = true). Or... is this too simplistic? I'm open to hearing better ways of doing this, I had a look around on the web but there aren't many solid examples for C#. My video is playing within a WPF application in real-time so nested for loops are to be avoided.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You could check whether the "majority" of the result matrix is black (you choose the threshhold" or you could do like a contour detenction, put a bounding box over motion (biggest contour) and display that as a mask over the original video. Im sure there are more ways, these 2 are off the top of my head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a simple way to do it, may not be the best but it does work.

```
public bool motion = false;
public Mat currentFrame = new Mat();
public Mat prevFrame = new Mat();
public Mat absDiffImage = new Mat();
public Mat grayImage = new Mat();

public Point[][] frameContours;
public HierarchyIndex[] external;
public Mat frameThresh = new Mat();

Cv2.CvtColor(currentFrame, currentFrame, ColorConversionCodes.BGRA2GRAY);
Cv2.Absdiff(currentFrame, prevFrame, absDiffImage);
Cv2.Threshold(absDiffImage, frameThresh, 80, 255, ThresholdTypes.Binary);
Cv2.FindContours(frameThresh, out frameContours, out external, RetrievalModes.List, ContourApproximationModes.ApproxSimple);

if (frameContours.Length > 20)
{
    motion = true;
}
else
{
    motion = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could for example convert the matrix to an image. That should give you access to all the image manipulation functions. For example `ThresholdBinary` to make pixels either zero or a given value, and `CountNonZero`. That should give you some tools balance how much things need to change, and how large area need to change.